# How sites show non-SSL content, after user login with SSL, WITHOUT compromisse Authorization Cookies (or they compromise?)

Tags: session, ssl, cookies, https

**Short Description:**

How sites do a User LogIn SSL, and keep user logged in, on non-SSL pages without be susceptible to session hijaking?

**Detailed Description:**

So, We all know that the LogIn page must be SSL based. And We all (may) know that We can't share the Auth Cookie created in this SSL login, with non-SSL pages, because a hacker can copy this cookie (intercepting the non-SSL pages) and impersonate our dear user.

**What's burning my brain:**

Somebody please show me the path: How can StackOverflow, and Steam (http://steamcommunity.com/) keep me logged in, without be susceptible to session hijacking?

Ok, The first thing I thought was: "They have two sessions set when I execute my log in, one secure and other not secured. The not secured is used whenever the content is not sensible."

The problem is: They show sensible information in non-SSL pages, (StackOverflow show my profile, let me do Questions... The Steam shows my profile that I've set as private, then it's a sensible information).

What are they doing? Some hacker can really steal my cookie, impersonate my StackOverflow profile and write as Me, Or Am I missing some really clever protection that I don't know?